# Dot is missed in email link

Tags: email, hyperlink

We send email to our customers and have link like this

http://www.my-site.no/uploads/171116-091639-19.jpg

The problem that sometimes some of dots is missed, for example

like this:

`http://www.my-site.no/uploads/171116-091639-19jpg
http://www.my-siteno/uploads/171116-091639-19.jpg`

we use sendgrid to send messages and use `link tracking` feature there

Does anybody meet that issue? or what can we do to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure that the links are correct before you send the email? What happens when you send a test to yourself?

I've worked with various ESPs and have never had this issue, even with link tracking which should just append some parameter or create a redirect link.

Comment: yeah, and that is the problem, we store each email in db before it's sent, so in db every link is fine, but we use old and third-party tool for sending them, I can suppose it's the reason of that issue, but it's strange cause that tool just get data from db and send via sendgrid by smtp

Comment: for me it works fine, it happened really few times with our customers, could that be some email client issue?